# Blog keeps redirecting to the contact page

Tags: redirect, plugin-contact-form-7

I just added a new contact page on my blog, and I use the Contact Form 7 plugin. For some reason, when I go to my blog now, it constantly redirects to the new contact page! I looked at .htaccess files - nothing seem to have been changes. Anybody has any idea why this is happening?

Even when I remove the contact page, my blog still redirects to /blog/contact.

**Edit:** I managed to find the cause of the problem, and I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

After looking for the problem for a while, I decided to search in the MySQL database for the word "contact", and I noticed that a table called `wp_redirection_items` indeed contained an entry which redirected from `/blog/` to `/blog/contact`. A quick Google search has led me to [this page](http://urbangiraffe.com/support/topic/home-page-is-redirecting-to-another-wp-page-without-my-instruction-to-do-so), explaining the problem - it's caused by the `Redirection` plugin's URL Monitoring feature. I ended up manually removing the offending entry from the database, and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What settings have been set in the reading tab of the settings menu? if the radio button 'static page' is selected, switch it over to your latest posts

Comment: No, this was not it, I checked. I figured out what's wrong and I fixed it. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted that entry from the table but my home page is still being redirected to a newly added contact me page. Any further help on this?

Comment: This is not a classic forum, you should not post a followup question as an "answer". Instead, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of this page. You can then delete this "answer" to keep the site clean.